# Keypad not getting opened up when we tap on a text field in iPhoneX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have two text fields for the user to reset his password:
First to enter a new password.
Second to confirm the password by re-entering it.

I am facing the issue only on the second text field (only for iPhone X) that when we tap on it once, the keypad does not open up (only option to "paste" shows up).
If we tap it again after tapping somewhere else on the screen, then the keypad opens up.
What could be the reason for this and how to fix this?

I have checked that when I tap on it first, then I can see just the top of the keypad appearing from the bottom of the screen but it does not completely open up.

Here are these two text fields:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="create_pin"
                                        name="create_pin" maxlength="20" minlength="8" required="" required aria-required="true"  aria-describedby="tooltip_password" 
                                        placeholder="" onchange="registerWidget.parsleyValidate(this);"
                                        data-parsley-pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()+-])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()+-]{8,}$"
                                        data-parsley-required-message="${requiredPin}" data-parsley-length-message="${validPin}"
                                        data-parsley-pattern-message="${validPin}" autocomplete="off"
                                        readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">



<input type="password" class="form-control" id="re_enter_pin"
                                        name="re_enter_pin" maxlength="20" required=""
                                        placeholder="${placeHolderRenterPin}" onchange="registerWidget.parsleyValidate(this);"
                                        data-parsley-required-message="${requiredPin}"
                                        autocomplete="off"
                                        readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the reason was that some other function is getting called on the same event that was supposed to trigger the keypad opening. That function was somehow inhibiting this default action of opening the keypad.

So, in my case, removing the below lines worked for me:

autocomplete="off"
readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"

Comment: Dear reviewers, I added this answer yesterday but was deleted. Not sure, why. Didn't get proper reason for that. This solution worked for me so want to share with others so that it can be helpful for those who are stuck on the same issue.